# Spreadsheet Script, match with wildcard and different cases

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, wildcard, spreadsheet

I am having trouble executing the Spreadsheet script below.
I think there are two mistakes but I do not know how to fix.
Could anyone help it to fix it?

## 1:Wildcard

```
if(original_date=='....-..-..')
```

## 2:if synteax

```
if(original_date=='....-..-..')
 {condition="matched"}
```

## Detail

On the spreadsheet, there are two columns.
The first columns have dates in a format as YYYY-MM-DD such as 2020-04-21.
But sometimes, they have different formats such as 04/21/2020.
The second columns are empty.
Only when the first column cell has the "YYYY-MM-DD" format, I want to copy the cell into the second cell in the second column.
*They have 10 rows.

**Here is the script.**

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  for(let i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
  original_date_range = sheet.getRange(i, 1);
  original_date = original_date_range.getValue();
  cleaned_date_range = sheet.getRange(i, 2);
  var condition = "";
  
  if(original_date=='....-..-..')
  {condition="matched"}
  
  switch(condition)
  {
  case "matched":
  cleaned_date_range.setValue(original_date);
  case "":
  cleaned_date_range.setValue("");
  break;
  }
  
  }
```

Comment: Dates are represented on a spreadsheet as a number and then formatted to look like a date. The same number in different cells can be formatted as "dd-mmm-yyyy" and "mm/dd/yy" and "yyyy mm dd". If you are specifically looking at the formatting, then check the format properties of the cells in question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

**1.Wildcard**

```
The date "2020-04-25" can be written as /\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}/
```

**2.If syntax**

```
(Wildcard).test(string to check) is going to give you true/false output
```

In summary, 
if you want to execute different tasks through the verification of date format such as 2020-04-25,

```
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var limit = sheet1.getLastRow()
  for(let i=4; i<=10; i++) //You can add more rows if you have
  {
  var orignal_date_cell = sheet1.getRange(i, 1);
  var orignal_date_cell_value = orignal_date_cell.getValue();
  var target_date_cell = sheet1.getRange(i,2);
  if ((/\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}/).test(orignal_date_cell_value))
  {
  target_date_cell.setValue(orignal_date_cell_value);
  }
  }
```